# Manipulate JSON from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

I have the following JSON data.

```
[{'connectionId': 1, 'roomId': 140, 'connectionName': 'Hai'},
 {'connectionId': 1, 'roomId': 147, 'connectionName': 'Hai'},
 {'connectionId': 2, 'roomId': 100, 'connectionName': 'hello'},
 {'connectionId': 2, 'roomId': 140, 'connectionName': 'hello'}]
```

I want to retrieve response like the below from the above data using typescript

```
  [ { 'connectionId': 1, 'roomId': [ 140, 147] , 'connectionName': 'Hai'} 
  , { 'connectionId': 2, 'roomId': [ 100, 140] , 'connectionName': 'hello'} 
  ]
```

How to solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way...

```js
const data = 
      [ { connectionId: 1, roomId: 140, connectionName: 'Hai' } 
      , { connectionId: 1, roomId: 147, connectionName: 'Hai' } 
      , { connectionId: 2, roomId: 100, connectionName: 'hello' } 
      , { connectionId: 2, roomId: 140, connectionName: 'hello' } 
      ] 
  , result = data.reduce((a,{connectionId,roomId,...more})=>
      {
      let p = a.find(x=>x.connectionId===connectionId)
      if(!p)
        {
        p = { connectionId, roomId:[],...more}
        a.push(p)
        }
      p.roomId.push(roomId)
      return a
      },[])
      
console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how to add one more key. question updated

Comment: @AbdulManaf, just add `, ...more` (see udate)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this: with C-style loops, for of, for in, reduce... here's one fairly clean way that should work for you:

```
const json = [{ connectionId: 1, roomId: 140 },
  { connectionId: 1, roomId: 147 },
  { connectionId: 2, roomId: 100 },
  { connectionId: 2, roomId: 140 },
]

const formatted = [...new Set(json.map((x) => x.connectionId))]
  .map((id) => ({
    connectionId: id,
    roomId: [json.filter((x) => x.connectionId === id).map(({ roomId }) => roomId)]
  }))
```